# material-ui component style customization – change color of select component to white

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, components, material-ui

I want to use a dropdown menu of the material-ui components (see https://material-ui.com/components/selects/). Therefore, I copied the specific component out of the example:

**Component**

```
return <div>
<FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.root}>
  <InputLabel ref={inputLabel} id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label">
    Plan
  </InputLabel>
  <Select
    labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
    id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
    value={age}
    onChange={handleChange}
    labelWidth={labelWidth}

  >
    <MenuItem value="">
      <em>None</em>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={10}>dsnfsdjfnsduifn</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

**Style**

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
root: {
  margin: theme.spacing(1),
  minWidth: 120,
  color: 'white',
  borderColor: 'white'
},}));
```

Because of my app design, I want to change the color of this dropdown menu to white. At the moment the component looks like this:

[image: need to be white]

As you can see in the component, the variant is outlined. As I understand the documentation (https://material-ui.com/api/select/)  I have to overwrite the .MuiSelect-outlined class but I am not sure how I can do this. Unfortunately, the manual only describes the style of simple buttons and not how I can change the style of more complex components like these.
I hope someone can give me an example how I can change the color of the outline, the text and the arrow to white.

Comment: set className={classes.root} to <Select /> and try again

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now the text is white but the outline and the arrow is still black.

Comment: write another Style for FormControl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go

```
.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline {
    border-color: #fff;//for border color
}
 .MuiSelect-icon {
    color: #fff;// for icon drop down icon color
}
.MuiInputLabel-root {
    color: #fff;// for lable color
}
```

For `focus` just add the parent `.Mui-focused` selector on these

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Where do I have to put these lines into my code?

Comment: @ling either you should write that in global 'style.css' or in 'component styles' or above component html using 'style' tag

Comment: I have created an own CSS file for this component, which I have imported via `import './TrainingPlanSelector.css';`. I didn’t add anything to the HTML return of the hook. Unfortunately, the dropdown menu still looks the same and the CSS file don’t has any impact to the style. Do I have to add the class names, which you gave me to any of the given tags and if yes: which className for which tag?

Comment: @Ling what is the directory structure of `TrainingPlanSelector.css` i m an it location, i thinks its a component style so you need to use `/deep/` selector before each style like `/deep/ .MuiSelect-icon{ border-color: #fff !important;}` and an `!important` to override default style.

Comment: Thank you very much! After I added the `!important` tag, now the border color etc. is white.

Answer (score 0):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
select: {
  borderColor: 'white'
},
fomrControl{
  margin: theme.spacing(1),
  minWidth: 120,
  color: 'white',
}
}));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have the same problem after I added the styles to the corresponding components.

Comment: try to make your sample in jsfiddle for more test please